# Adding sugar for secondary fermentation?

Tags: fermentation, sugar

My first go at wine making. My Red wine Og was 1.06 and primary fermentation final OG is 1.00. should i add more sugar for secondary fermentation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a homebrewer but the principles between cider, beer and wine making are similar. I've added sugars to cider and beer before post-primary and it boosted the ABV but also thinned the body of the beverage out. It was still drinkable,just not as much character as usual.

One concern with this is contamination. Straight table sugar isn't exactly easy to sanitize with star san, and heating it to pastuerize it can cause other problems. You may want to consider pastuerized fruit juice. The sugar is still there, but you are less likely to contaminate things. Just make sure to stay away from juice with Sodium Benzoate,  Potassium Sorbate or other preservatives as this will render your fermentation ineffective.